# Enzyme/React/Redux - Invariant Violation.

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, mocha.js, redux, enzyme

Have some legacy code that I wrote without unit tests (I know, I know, bad engi, no cookie), but we were in a rush and literally needed the site to go up in a matter of days.

Now I'm trying to pay off the technical debt.  Most of it's easy, but I still have to test the react components.  Trying to do so using JSDom and enzyme, but often get this error:

> Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in either the context or
>   props of "Connect(ThankYou)". Either wrap the root component in a
>   , or explicitly pass "store" as a prop to
>   "Connect(ThankYou)".

So my question is: What's causing this error, and how should I approach this? I'm sure I'll have more questions, but this is the big blocker for now.

So, here's the setup for the test:

```
import React from 'react';
import chai from 'chai';
const expect = chai.expect;
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme';

import ThankYou from '../src/frontend/js/containers/ThankYou';

describe('<ThankYou />', () => {
  it('is trying to get React testing to work', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ThankYou />);
    //(I know this test *will* fail, but it's failing in the wrong way.)
    expect(wrapper).to.eql({}); 
  });
});
```

Here's the component itself.

```
class ThankYou extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <Paper zDepth={1} >
        <div>
          {thankYou.map((pgraph, i) => (<div key={"pg" + i}>
            {pgraph[this.props.language]}
          </div>))}
        </div>
        <Social />
      </Paper>
    );
  }
}

// reduxify is a library I wrote which maps 
// state, actions, and dispatch to props. 
// source: https://github.com/brianboyko/reduxify/blob/master/reduxify.js
export default reduxify(actions, ['language'], ThankYou);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are importing the class wrapped in `reduxify` into your tests. This component expects to be passed the redux `store` via context, so the error you are seeing is warning you this is not the case.

You could mock the `context` to provide a dummy store, or import the component without the `reduxify` wrapper and instead test that component:

```
// Export the class before it becomes wrapped
export class ThankYou extends Component {
  ...
}

export default reduxify(actions, ['language'], ThankYou);


// Update the test to import the basic class
import { ThankYou } from '../src/frontend/js/containers/ThankYou';

describe('<ThankYou />', () => {
  it('is trying to get React testing to work', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<ThankYou />);
    expect(wrapper).to.eql({}); 
  });
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly it, and I can't believe I didn't think of this myself. I actually now remember thinking this exact thing, but right before I went to bed, and forgot about it until you reminded me that this was the thing. 

Probably too much info, but thank you!